# How to pass mongo query result to an asp.net view via model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, mongodb, model-view-controller, model

I want to query a mongo collection, but I can't access the column values and don't know how to write them into the model, how can I pass the query results into the view via a model?

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult HelloMongo()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("xxxxxx");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("y");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Countries");        
        var documents = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();

        foreach (var document in documents)
        {
            // how to write documents into Model?
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Don't know if the model looks ok

Model code:

```
public class CountryModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("CountryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("CountryName")]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public CountryModel(string v2, string v3)
    {  
        CountryCode = v2;
        CountryName = v3;
    }
}
```

I want to display the query results in a table

View:

```
<h2>Mongo Table Content</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Country Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Country Name
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var document in Model.documents)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model.CountryCode
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.CountryName
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to ask this: what kind of object contained inside `documents`? Can you clarify it by debugging? If you can explain that, I can assume that you have `var viewModel = new CountryModel();` and want to put those data contained inside `documents` into `viewModel` then pass it to view.

Comment: The type of `documents` is `System.Collections.Generic.List<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>`, the type of the objects inside `documents` is `MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument`